# Multiple boxplot with seaborn, but not within the same frame

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn, boxplot

In case of pandas boxplot, we could use:

```
for column in df:
    plt.figure()
    df.boxplot([column])
```

What could be done equivalently using `seaborn`, I want to plot multiple boxplots, but not in the same frame, rather for every column individually in loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an `Axes` object to sns.boxplot:

```
for column in df:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    sns.boxplot(df[column], ax=ax)
```

Comment: Thanks @Stef, would be possible as a vertical plot, rather than horizontal

Comment: Yes, use `y=df[column]` instead of just `x=df[column]` which is short for only `df[column]`